# How can we format group of data in DataGridView of Winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

In my Winforms 4.5 app, I am binding a DataGridView to a SQL Server Db table called Products. The table has a column called Category that displays a category the product is in. For example:

```
C1  P11
C1  P112
C2  P21
C2  P22
C2  P23
C3  P31
..  ...
C4  P41
C4  P42
..  ...
```

I would like to set the alternating row style of the DataGridView based on each group (not for each row). So, in the above example, the first two rows (group C1) would have default background color, the next three rows (group C2) would have a dark grey background color, the rows for group C3 would have the default background color, the rows for group C4 would have dark grey background color, and so on. How can I achieve this. Please note that the number of rows in each group would change dynamically based on the data entry by the user; and the demo data shown above is not the real data.

I tried the following two MSDN articles with their examples but they are not quite what I want above:

1. [Set Alternating Row Styles for the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txth0a6h(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [Customize Data Formatting in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1cc356h(v=vs.80).aspx)

**EDIT**
In the real data, the categories would not contain numbers in front of them. Real example of categories could be: Fruits, Vegetables, Dairy,...

Answer (score 0):

Not certain that this is going to be the most performant way of achieving what you're after, but I might try just manually setting the back color of each row based on the logic that you have defined here (essentially based on a group value). So something that might look like this:

First setup some mock data:

```
public class DAL
{
    public static DataTable GetMockData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ProductId", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
        dt.Columns.Add("ProductName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("ProductCategory", Type.GetType("System.String"));

        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Apple", "Fruit" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Banana", "Fruit" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Pear", "Fruit" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "Potato", "Vegetable" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, "Celery", "Vegetable" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6, "Carrot", "Vegetable" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 7, "Hominy", "Vegetable" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 8, "Wine", "Beverage" });
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Next show Form that will consume this data and alternate background color of row based on ProductCategory:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataTable dt = DAL.GetMockData();
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> categoryNumber = GetUniqueCategories(sender as DataGridView);
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells["ProductCategory"].Value != null)
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = GetRowColor(categoryNumber[row.Cells["ProductCategory"].Value.ToString()]);
    }
}

private Color GetRowColor(int categoryNumber)
{
    if (categoryNumber % 2 == 0)
        return Color.White; //default row color
    else
        return Color.LightGray; //alternate row color
}
private Dictionary<string, int> GetUniqueCategories(DataGridView dt)
{
    int i = 0;
    Dictionary<string, int> categoryNumber = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells["ProductCategory"].Value != null)
        {
            if (!categoryNumber.ContainsKey(row.Cells["ProductCategory"].Value.ToString()))
            {
                categoryNumber.Add(row.Cells["ProductCategory"].Value.ToString(), i);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return categoryNumber;
}
```

Comment: Dan, your suggested code is assuming the category name would have a single digit number at the end. As I stated in my original post, the data shown in the example is not the real data. I have added an "Edit" at the end for further clarification.

Comment: Ahh...I see. One could argue that is perhaps a separate matter of how to oscillate between values that are not numeric, but I can also see that may be part of the original problem. I've updated my code example to solve for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know each category, you can define a color for each group beforehand. Otherwise you'd need to make an color generator for groups, where the total count is unknown. Here's one approach:

```
    public static void Categorize(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        // Set colors for each category
        Color apples = Color.Red,
              bananas = Color.Yellow,
              oranges = Color.Orange;

        // Loop the rows
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            // Read category
            string category = row.Cells["GroupColumn"].Value.ToString();

            // Set color according to category
            switch (category)
            {
                case "Apple": row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = apples; return;
                case "Banana": row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = bananas; return;

                // If the group wasn't listed, skip
                default: return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ashton, in your example, the Apple, Banana,.. are not categories these are the products inside the category "Fruits". Moreover, a)the data is dynamic, that is, the more categories can be added etc. and b) I need to implement the alternating row style as explained in my post.

Comment: You need an color generator for dynamic categories. The example above is for designs where you know the categories beforehand.