# Change row background color for similar rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have asked the similar question moment ago but it was for the linq. I have a list and linq is used to group by the records based on 3 columns. I have bind the list to a DataGridView and it is showing the records as desired.

The original records are like this,

```
var list = new List<Users>()
{ 
  new Users() { FirstName = "A1", LastName= "A2", MiddleName = "A3" },      
  new Users() { FirstName = "B1", LastName= "A2", MiddleName = "B3" },
  new Users() { FirstName = "C1", LastName= "C2", MiddleName = "C3" },
  new Users() { FirstName = "A1", LastName= "A2", MiddleName = "A3" },
  new Users() { FirstName = "D1", LastName= "C2", MiddleName = "A3" },
  new Users() { FirstName = "A1", LastName= "A2", MiddleName = "B3" },
  new Users() { FirstName = "B1", LastName= "B2", MiddleName = "A3" },
};
```

After applying the linq,

```
var sorted = list.OrderBy(l => l.FirstName).ThenBy(l => l.LastName).ThenBy(l => l.MiddleName).ToList();
```

The records are ordered by FirstName, LastName and MiddleName. So all rows are the group of similar rows. I hope that I have explained this well.

Now I want to use alternate row color of Winform DataGridView but for similar rows and not for alternating rows.

A similar question is asked here,
[How can we format group of data in DataGridView of Winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468667/how-can-we-format-group-of-data-in-datagridview-of-winform)

but this is based on group by of one column. But I am not using group by and have rows categorized into groups based on similar values. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to color rows having same `FirstName`, `MiddleName` and `LastName` separately?

Comment: @X-TECH  Yes that is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    private static readonly Random _random = new Random();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadDataGridView();
    }

    private void LoadDataGridView()
    {
        var list = new List<Users>()
        { 
          new Users { FirstName = "A1", LastName= "A2", MiddleName = "A3" },
          new Users { FirstName = "B1", LastName= "A2", MiddleName = "B3" },
          new Users { FirstName = "C1", LastName= "C2", MiddleName = "C3" },
          new Users { FirstName = "A1", LastName= "A2", MiddleName = "A3" },
          new Users { FirstName = "D1", LastName= "C2", MiddleName = "A3" },
          new Users { FirstName = "A1", LastName= "A2", MiddleName = "B3" },
          new Users { FirstName = "B1", LastName= "B2", MiddleName = "A3" },
          new Users { FirstName = "D1", LastName= "C2", MiddleName = "A3" },
          new Users { FirstName = "B1", LastName= "B2", MiddleName = "A3" },
          new Users { FirstName = "A1", LastName= "A2", MiddleName = "A3" }
        };
        foreach (var user in list)
        {
            var localCopy = user;
            var assignedColor = list.Where(x => x.FirstName == localCopy.FirstName && x.LastName == localCopy.LastName && x.MiddleName == localCopy.MiddleName && x.BackColor != null).Select(x => x.BackColor).FirstOrDefault();
            user.BackColor = assignedColor ?? Color.FromKnownColor(GetRandomConsoleColor());
            var index = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = user.FirstName;
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = user.LastName;
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value = user.MiddleName;
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = user.BackColor ?? Color.White;
        }
    }

    private static KnownColor GetRandomConsoleColor()
    {
        var consoleColors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
        return (KnownColor)consoleColors.GetValue(_random.Next(consoleColors.Length));
    }
}

public class Users
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public Color? BackColor { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

EDIT:

For light random colors, replace the following line of code

```
user.BackColor = assignedColor ?? Color.FromKnownColor(GetRandomConsoleColor());
```

with

```
user.BackColor = assignedColor ?? Color.FromArgb(Random.Next(200, 255), Random.Next(150, 255), Random.Next(150, 255));
```

Or you can may be find more efficient way to generate light random colors :)

Comment: Bundle of thanks. Let me have a moment to go through this.